# SQL Server : expand rows and transpose columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

To paint the picture, this is my current table:

```
Name    Size1    Size2    Size3    Size4
-----------------------------------------
Test    100      200      0        10
Test 2  50       0        100      50
Test 3  70       100      60       40
```

This is an antiquated table and makes slicing and dicing very hard. What I'd like to do, is transpose the size columns and expand the rows depending on how many sizes.

For example:

```
Name    Size    Values
----------------------
Test    1       100
Test    2       200
Test    4        10
Test 2  1        50
Test 2  3       100
Test 2  4        50
Test 3  1        70
Test 3  2       100
Test 3  3        60
Test 3  4        40
```

My question: is this even possible, or am I dreaming?

Scratching my head to the point of baldness ... would appreciate any insights!

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using  `cross apply (values ())` to unpivot your data:

```
select t.Name, v.Size, v.Value
from t
  cross apply (values 
    (1,Size1),(2,Size2),(3,Size3),(4,Size4)
    ) v (Size, Value)
where v.Value<>0
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/PPLRR33530

returns:

```
+--------+------+-------+
|  Name  | Size | Value |
+--------+------+-------+
| Test   |    1 |   100 |
| Test   |    2 |   200 |
| Test   |    4 |    10 |
| Test 2 |    1 |    50 |
| Test 2 |    3 |   100 |
| Test 2 |    4 |    50 |
| Test 3 |    1 |    70 |
| Test 3 |    2 |   100 |
| Test 3 |    3 |    60 |
| Test 3 |    4 |    40 |
+--------+------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can.
You need [UNPIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/id-id/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx).

here is an example :

```
--Create the table and insert values as portrayed in the previous example.
DECLARE @pvt TABLE 
(VendorID int, Emp1 int, Emp2 int,
    Emp3 int, Emp4 int, Emp5 int);

INSERT INTO @pvt VALUES (1,4,3,5,4,4);
INSERT INTO @pvt VALUES (2,4,1,5,5,5);
INSERT INTO @pvt VALUES (3,4,3,5,4,4);
INSERT INTO @pvt VALUES (4,4,2,5,5,4);
INSERT INTO @pvt VALUES (5,5,1,5,5,5);

--Unpivot the table.
SELECT VendorID, Employee, Orders
FROM 
   (SELECT VendorID, Emp1, Emp2, Emp3, Emp4, Emp5
   FROM @pvt) p
UNPIVOT
   (Orders FOR Employee IN 
      (Emp1, Emp2, Emp3, Emp4, Emp5)
)AS unpvt;
```